# How to start animation instantly after initializing the Scene in Java FX with FXML

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2, fxml

I am writing an application in Java FX with some fancy animations.
I want to slide in a text node **text_1** from the left side to the 20% of the available stage width.

```
public class SplashController implements Initializable {
public Democracy parent = null;

@FXML
public Text text1;
public Text text2;
public Text text3;

   public void animateIntro() {
       TranslateTransition t1_transl_1 = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1500d),text1);
       t1_transl_1.setFromX(-100d);
       t1_transl_1.setByX((double)((20/100) * parent.getStage().getWidth()+100));
       // Here Democracy class has a static method to return its instance, which is assigned on class creation. I want to slide in the text_1 node to 20% of the total window width.
       //Here I am always getting **NaN**
       System.out.println((20d/100d) * parent.getStage().getWidth()); // Getting NaN
       System.out.println(parent.getStage().getScene().getWidth()); // Throwing Exception
       FadeTransition t1_fade_in = new FadeTransition(new Duration(1000d), text1);
       t1_fade_in.setFromValue(0);
       t1_fade_in.setToValue(100d);

       ParallelTransition t1_ptrans_1 = new ParallelTransition(text1,t1_fade_in,t1_transl_1);
       //With parallel transition I want to fade in and slide in the node at the same time.
       t1_ptrans_1.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        parent = Democracy.getInstance();
        animateIntro();
    }    


}
```

When I used Netbeans' built in Debugger, I found out that most of the values inside the stage variable of parent is null. I think it is because that stage is not fully initialized, I'm getting null values. Is there any work around to detect the complete initialization? Please Help me...

**Edit** : Even after I added a

```
while(!parent.getStage().isShowing()) {
try{
    sleep(100);
} catch(Exception e){}
```

loop to ensure that animateIntro() is only called after the stage is visible, I am still unable to get the width. Please help me to solve this..

Comment: what is the responsibility of the `Democracy` class ?

Comment: more importantly, how do you call this? where do you set up and call the FXMLLoader?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind a listener to the stages [widthProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#widthProperty) and wait for changes that actually contain numbers.